# About the experimental measurement of neutrino magnetic moment and its value

Tags: particle-physics, neutrinos, beyond-the-standard-model

Massive neutrinos, be it Dirac or majorana, have magnetic moment. See [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/397099/how-can-neutrinos-have-a-magnetic-moment-in-spite-of-being-neutral-and-elementar?rq=1&utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/304135/the-magnetic-moment-of-a-particle-and-a-neutrino) and [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/381885/do-neutrinos-have-magnetic-moment).

$\bullet$ *How is it measured (or can be measured) in real experiments? What are the (upper and lower) bounds on the value of the neutrino magnetic moment from direct measurements?*

$\bullet$ *Does the measured values of neutrino observables i.e., the oscillation angles, Dirac CP phase and bound on the sum of neutrino masses constrain the value of the neutrino magnetic moment?*

Comment: The [Particle Data Group literature review](http://pdglive.lbl.gov/Particle.action?node=S066) is probably the authoritative source for this question.

Comment: The question would be more meaningful after good-faith absorption of a [stock review](https://arxiv.org/abs/0812.3646).

Comment: [Giunti-Studenikin (2015)](https://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.87.531).

Comment: @CosmasZachos  In arxiv  https://arxiv.org/abs/1403.6344