# Can a magnetic field exist without an electric field present?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, reference-frames, electric-fields

I know an electric field can exist without a magnetic field as in the case where you have a stationary point charge.

But, magnetic fields are created *by moving charges* so wouldn't you always need an electric field to have a magnetic field? Even in the case of permanent magnets, from what I know, it's the aligned moving electrons in the atoms of the material which cause the magnetic properties so doesn't that mean there's always an electric field in order to have a magnetic field?

Comment: Electrostatics + relativistic transformations = magnetism as shown here http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/db275/concepts/EM.pdf

Comment: „I know an electric field can exist without a magnetic field as in the case where you have a stationary point charge.“ that is wrong Electrons, protons and even neutrons have a magnetic dipole moment. And magnetic fields could be made by the alignment and self-holding of the electrons (or even the protons) magnetic dipole moments.

Comment: A stationary point charge, what is that? How can anything be stationary in the universe? All motion, and position is *relative*. For an observer that is moving relative to the point charge, will certainly feel its magnetic field. Is the point charge static and has no magnetic field, or is it moving and has? Whether or not something is an electric or magnetic field is not a property that can be exclusively determined across all observers. They are aspects of the same thing.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The "magnetic field" is a concept within classical electrodynamics. Maxwell's equations were developed in the mid 19th century at a time where basic atomic physics was still a nascent field of study.

Viewed in the contemporary historical context, a permanent magnet is a perfectly fine example of a magnetic field without an electric field. Within the theory of classical electrodynamics, there is no explanation for why the magnetic field exists, only that it does exist, and how it's related to the electric field. Permanent magnets have a magnetic field as an intrinsic, fundamental property, similar to the reasons rocks have mass. They just do.

In the past one and a half centuries other theories have been developed. For example [the magnetic field can be explained by special relativity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1TKSfAkWWN0) as length contraction apparently creating a charge imbalance, so it could be said the magnetic field doesn't exist as a fundamental property but is rather a manifestation of the electric field in moving reference frame, and [quantum physics explains permanent magnets as moving charges at sub-atomic scales](https://youtu.be/hFAOXdXZ5TM).

So viewed in the context of modern physics, there's really no need for a fundamental magnetic field at all since it can be explained in terms of the electric field and motion.

The discovery of a magnetic monopole would change this, but although it would bring an elegant symmetry to the kinds of particles that exist, no evidence of a magnetic monopole has been found by experiment yet.

Comment: To be precise: permanent ferromagnets are quite often no orbital- but spin ferromagnets, i.e., moving charges are not necessary.. The story is therefore more complex as described in the video you link to.

Comment: @sagittarius_a still some charge movement is involved in spin, if thought as rotation around an axis

Answer (score 10):

I suppose this is a variant of Quantum spaghettification's answer, but an obvious example is a [current loop](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/curloo.html), as used in electromagnets since humans first discovered electricity.

There is no *net* electric field because there are equal numbers of positive and negative charges so their fields balance out. However there is a magnetic dipole due to the motion of the electrons.

Comment: But what about the potential difference that causes the motion of electrons?

Answer (score 8):

No you can have a magnetic field without an electric field. Consider a rod with an equal number of positive and negative charges (such that they are equally spaced). Let the positive move to the left with speed $v$ and the negative to the right with speed $v$. This will result in a magnetic field but no electric field.

Comment: So a magnetic field can exist alone if the electric field cancels? I.e. the net electric field is 0?

Comment: Yep exactly. Actually if you get into the details (i.e. consider relativity) for any system where you have both a magnetic and electric field you can always move into a frame (i.e change your speed) such that there is either just an electric or just a magnetic field.

Comment: This is incorrect. If a system consists of a single charge, there is no frame without an electric field. Also in your answer you have moving charges that produce an electric field. It cancels out macroscopically, but not microscopically. Strictly speaking there is no magnetic field without an electric field unless you use approximations.

Comment: @safesphere I was trying to be careful with my wording in the previous comment by saying "either just" I was implicitly implying what you are stating. Concerning the second part of this comment, I also agree that my answer (along with John Rennie's) is evoking a coarse graining procedure.

Comment: Don't the magnetic fields of the two currents cancel?

Comment: @garyp No. This can be seen with the right-hand rule or more simply by the fact that you have a net current.

Comment: Oh yeah.  (Brain malfunction.)

Comment: This is like saying that a plane surface can be a line if only you look at it from a certain angle. True, but constructed to be true - an observer looking from another frame could describe the whole situation as purely electric - with no magnetic field.

Comment: @StianYttervik If I am interpreting you correctly this comes back down to safesphere's comment. It turns out if there is a frame where it is purely magnetic then there cannot exist a frame where it is purely electric (this is because $E^2-B^2$ is Lorentz invariant and if negative in one frame must be negative in all frames). Although I agree there will exist frames where there is both a magnetic and electric field.

Comment: @Quantumspaghettification Well, maybe I was a bit flippant - you are correct and I was wrong: My point was to convey that this "purely electric" case, this is not a property of a thing, it is dependant on the relationship between the thing and the observer, the frame. It is electromagnetic - to find the case or the frame where it manifests as either one or the other is theoretical masturbation. Fun but not very productive - especially when there is reason to believe OP still sees it as "one or the other"...

Answer (score 6):

In one sense, it is an easy question, as others have pointed out. It is fairly simple to construct examples of cases with zero electric field and non-zero magnetic field.

In another sense, it's not a trivial question to answer. For example, if you see only a magnetic field in one frame, then you will see magnetic and electric field in another frame that is shifted by a change in velocity. Then there is the example of the Ahronov-Bohm effect. In this case, you have a region where both the electric and magnetic fields are zero, but an electron still feels an electromagnetic force.

The fundamental thing is the four-vector potential $A_\mu$. The electric and magnetic fields are particular arrangements of particular derivatives of this field. It is $A_\mu$ that appears in equations governing electromagnetism, such as Maxwell's equation or Dirac's equation. In several important special cases we can ignore $A_\mu$ and work with the $E_i$ and $B_i$ fields. But the fundamental understanding is always going to be based in $A_\mu$.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but I would *not* say that electrons "feel a force" in a zero EM fields due to the AB-effect. There is a phase shift, but macroscopically the electrons behavior is indistinguishable from there being no force.

Answer (score 5):

At a [fundamental elementary particle level](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model), the answer is that as long as no magnetic monopoles are detected, then a magnetic field dipole needs a charged particle.

The [electron has a magnetic moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_magnetic_moment):

> In atomic physics, the electron magnetic moment, or more specifically the electron magnetic dipole moment, is the magnetic moment of an electron caused by its intrinsic properties of spin and electric charge.

There [are only limits](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/718/6/062076/pdf) for a magnetic moment of the neutrino, a neutral particle with a very small mass. Have a look at my answer here for [further links for neutrinos.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/304135/the-magnetic-moment-of-a-particle-and-a-neutrino)

Comment: How about the neutron? It has a magnetic dipole moment and it is magnetically alignable.

Comment: @HolgerFiedler  it is not an elementary particle, it is made up of charged quarks and a  magnetic moment is composite from them and their "moving" charges.

Comment: Anna why I had know your answer in advance? Neutron is electrical neutral and has a spin aka a magnetic dipole moment. All other about made of quarks has to be mentioned only because the 100 years old thought about circulating currents which are the only source of magnetic field. And this is obsolet. An electron in rest - not composed off any quarks - has a magnetic dipole moment aka spin. It’s an intrinsic property. Without any movement nor revolution nor rotation of the electron.

Comment: @HolgerFiedler  it happens that the quark content of the neutron is an experimental fact. The neutron is composite. My answer is about the elementary particle building blocks  of the standard model.

Comment: No question that the neutron is composed of quarks. My doubt is about the need of movement (acceleration) or rotation as the only source for magnetic fields.

Comment: @ HolgerFiedler you do not need movement or rotation. There are spin ferromagnets. In this case, the electrons can move further apart if they align their spin. It is the exchange interaction.

Comment: @HolgerFiedler the electron has a dipole magnetic moment, and it is modeled as a point particle.

Answer (score 0):

In special relativity you can show that the following are invariant quantities, *i.e.* they are true in all frames: $$c ^2 \mathbf{B}^2-\mathbf{E}^2, \mathbf{B}\cdot\mathbf{E}.$$

It follows that, if one frame you have non-zero electric and magnetic fields that are perpendicular (so that $\mathbf{B}\cdot\mathbf{E} = 0$) such that $c^2 \mathbf{B}^2-\mathbf{E}^2 > 0$, then it is possible to go to a frame where the electric field is zero and the magnetic field is non-zero.